# JS make a list of multiple select-options in textField

Tags: javascript, multiple-select

```
 $().ready(function() {  
       $('#add').click(function() {  
        return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
       });  
       $('#remove').click(function() {  
        return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
       });  
      });
```

These two functions move selected options from one multiple select to another. I need to make a list with all added options' values(in #select2) in a input type hidden. And this input should be updated each time one of these functions is called.

Comment: May I ask why you want to copy them to a hidden field? Why not just use the values that #select2 has directly?

Comment: Because I need to send all options' values that appear in #select2 via $_POST to another php page and send this data to mysql.

Comment: @ Matt Ball -
I haven't tried anything because my js is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help

```
var yourInput = $('#IdOfYourInput');

$('#add').click(function() {  
    var opt = !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');
    yourInput.val($('#select2 option').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(','));
    return opt;
});
```

Removing is analogous:

```
$('#remove').click(function() {
    var opt =$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');
    yourInput.val($('#select2 option').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(','));
    opt.appendTo('#select1');  
    return opt;
});
```

I hope this is what your were aiming for..

Comment: var someContainer = $('.. create or look it up ..');
I should put here the input's ID right?

Comment: No, you probably want to store all your inputs in some <div> or <form>. This is the place to put the id of that element. If you have <form id='formForMyHiddenInputs'> then go with: var someContainer = $('#formForMyHiddenInputs'). Keep in mind that the form should already exist in your DOM structure -- just put an empty form somewhere in the code.

Comment: My idea is to make an <input type='text(or hidden)'> and take all values from #select2 and list them in the <input' value> separated with comma.